# IP Helper service uses 50-60% CPU every 1 minute for 3-4 seconds on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, ipv6, ipconfig, teredo

I have checked everything - all the processes in the process explorer. IP Helper service is causing CPU usage of over 50 % every 1 minute for 3-4 seconds then comes back to normal. In the task manager, the process is svchost.exe and the service is iphlpsvc.

Here's the result of "ipconfig /all" and "netsh interface teredo show state" command:

[image]

[image: Image2]

Also, uTorrent is not able to get the teredo address.